# I am redirected to the Meta Stack Exchange login page quite often

Tags: support, bug

I have been using Stack Overflow for a few months now.

The issue I am facing very often is when I click too fast or even twice on the notification icon and Stack Overflow icon sometimes it works as expected and sometimes it is redirecting to [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) login page though I am already logged in. It is happening quite often. The notification icon I mean we receive comments, edits, and answers notifications.

I noticed this stability issue in my mobile browser, Safari, and the Chrome browser on my laptop. I have been using these two browsers since I started my account on Stack Overflow and noticed this issue quite often.

I am not sure whether this is a bug or known behaviour.

Comment: You sure you aren't receiving notifications on Meta?

Comment: I am receiving notifications but the problem is when I click either notification icon or stackoverflow icon it some times redirecting to meta stackexchange login page. I don't have problem seeing notification numbers but the problem is only when I click on icon. I noticed this issue many times but it's a stability issue and I am sure on this

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I saw a question about this a while ago, and if I recall correctly, the answer was that while the page is loading, the base element of the notification icon redirects to the meta stack exchange homepage, and it doesn't become a notification button until more elements load on the page, so if you click it too fast, you get sent to Meta Stack Exchange. But I'm having trouble finding the reference, and I've only had it ever happen to me on mobile, not on the full browser.

Comment: Yes I missed that fact "if you click too fast" and I think it happened to me in laptop as well

Comment: The issue is not only with inbox icon but also stack overflow icon